# Regex multiline string individual matching groups

Tags: regex

Before I start, I know there are already many threads created on this topic, but I couldn't find anything specific to my use case, therefore I would like to ask this question with a pratical example based on what I found.

I have a multiline string that contain content I'm interested in it:

```
hello: "
  -foo=value1
  -bar=value2
  -baz=\"value3\"
"
```

I would like to match group on specific content within the multiline string, so that it matches on whatever within this string starts with `-`. The conditions are:

- Must start with the word `hello:`
- Match group each value starting with `-` within the string.
- Treat escaped quotes as part of the string: `\"`
- The string could also be as one liner and do the same matching: `hello: "-foo=value1"`

I came up with this pattern:

```php
hello:\s*"\s*-((?:[^"]|\n)*)"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't consider escaped strings and also doesn't match each result. I need the matched groups to repeat on each line within that string.

Comment: All captures of repeated groups can only be accessed in few languages, .NET and PyPi `regex` in Python. What is your programming environment?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, but for the sake of simplicity I didn't mentioned the programming language used. I use both, .NET, Python and Go for that pattern.

Comment: One possible way that I was thinking is first getting the string as a whole and then do another regex pass on the content within that string. But I'm sure there is a way of doing it in one go instead that out of my knowledge.

Comment: Does [this](https://ideone.com/oCzUuA) work for you? See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=hello%3a%5cs*%22%28%3f%3a%5cs*-%28%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%7c%5b%5e%5cn%22%5c%5c%5d%29%2b%29%29%2b%5cs*%22&i=hello%3a+%22%0d%0a++-foo%3dvalue1%0d%0a++-bar%3dvalue2%0d%0a++-baz%3d%5c%22value3%5c%22%0d%0a%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
hello:\s*"(?:\s*-((?:\\.|[^\n"\\])+))+\s*"
```

See [this regex demo at the .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=hello%3A%5Cs%2A%22%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2A-%28%28%3F%3A%5C%5C.%7C%5B%5E%5Cn%22%5C%5C%5D%29%2B%29%29%2B%5Cs%2A%22&i=hello%3A%20%22%0D%0A%20%20-foo%3Dvalue1%0D%0A%20%20-bar%3Dvalue2%0D%0A%20%20-baz%3D%5C%22value3%5C%22%0D%0A%22). *Details*:

- `hello:\s*"` - `hello:`, zero or more whitespaces, `"`
- `(?:\s*-((?:\\.|[^\n"\\])+))+` - one or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*-` zero or more occurrences of whitespace chars and then a `-`
  - `((?:\\.|[^\n"\\])+)` - Group 1: one or more occurrences of any escaped  char or any char but `\`, `"` and a newline
- `\s*"` - zero or more whitespace and then `"`.

See this C# demo:

```cs
var s = "hello: \"\n  -foo=value1\n  -bar=value2\n  -baz=\\\"value3\\\"\n\"";
var rx = @"hello:\s*""(?:\s*-((?:\\.|[^\n""\\])+))+\s*""";
var result = Regex.Match(s, rx)?.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach (var t in result)
    Console.WriteLine(t);
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##LU5BDoIwELzzig0XWhES5IYhPsTVpJIiJNA222LQ@PfaInuZnZmdyZq3G7SqvR9no8kByadcEwstZIOcJt1Aigqg6LVuX2JaZLXRh6A/Pe300yKmm1KHBVWanRNaQw3tPWgPKbtEKFhELL/Xe7hDvPGc8zz6ITML1w0xFv8orRTUDYzWI1iejD1sdpNAGEOjcmwTyk4Yt5C0rOLc@x8):

```py
import regex
s = 'hello: "\n  -foo=value1\n  -bar=value2\n  -baz=\\"value3\\"\n"';
rx = r'hello:\s*"(?:\s*-((?:\\.|[^\n"\\])+))+\s*"';
match = regex.search(rx, s)
if match:
    print(match.captures(1))
```

Output:

```
foo=value1
bar=value2
baz=\"value3\"
```

This approach won't work in Go. You need to extract the whole match with `hello:\s*"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*)"` and then split the Group 1 value with a line break sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much @Wiktor. Quick question, regarding your last pattern, why not `"((?:[^"\\]*\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*)"`? Is there a reason why the `[^"\\]*` not within the none capturing group? I'm curious because I noticed it works in both cases the same, so I might be missing something.

Comment: @MartinBrooker Correct is `"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*)"`. Any string between two `"`s with the support of any escape sequence inside. BTW, the question closure and downvotes on answers are totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a recursive approach to this problem. Here is my solution.

I'm taking this as my input text block which I guess have captured all possibilities:

```py
source_text = """
hello: "
  -foo=value1
  -bar=value2
  -baz=\"value3\"
"
bla: "
  -foo=value1
  -bar=value2
  -baz=\"value3\"
"
hello: "
  -foo=value1
  -bar=value2
  -baz=\"value3\"
"
hello: -baz=\"value3\"
hello: "-foo=value1"
"""
```

Recursively match the regex `hello:\s("|\\")?\n?(\s*-\w+=\\?"?\w+\\?"?\n?)+` which captures the required text in `match group 2`

```py
import re

all_matches = []

def get_all_matches(text):
    for block_match in re.finditer(r'hello:\s("|\\")?\n?(\s*-\w+=\\?"?\w+\\?"?\n?)+', text):
        match = block_match.group(2)
        if match:
            all_matches.append(re.sub("\n|\\s", '', match))
            full_match = block_match.group(0)
            get_all_matches(full_match.replace(match, ''))

get_all_matches(source_text)
```

Output

```py
print(all_matches)
```

```
['-baz="value3"', '-bar=value2', '-foo=value1', '-baz="value3"', '-bar=value2', '-foo=value1', '-baz="value3"', '-foo=value1"']
```